# Visual Studio 2019 CE Powershell Projects

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, debugging

I use VSCode to create powershell programs...
but I found the debugging capabilities a bit crude...

Recently with `PS5/OOP` I started to translate a lot of scripts `.cmd/.sh/...` to Powershell... 
also translated some executables to `.ps1` scripts with great success... granularity and code libraries are now much easier to manage...

Still I miss the VS2019 IDE facilities for variables/stack/classes and mainly the DEBUGGER quality...

?does anybody  knows if I can use VS2019 Community Edition to edit and debug Powershell... better: did VS2019 support Powershell projects... or is this feature planned for a future release???

Comment: VS_CE has a powershell plugin available. i do not know how well integrated the PoSh debugging is. from a quick scan of the VS with PoSh posts on the net, it seems that VS-CE supports powershell projects just as well as it supports any other language that has a plugin.

Comment: I know about Posh... but it is a 3rd party product... and you must buy a 1 year license... 

I think that Powershell being one of MS bets... and now with core versions is becoming more and more pervasive (I use it in Windows/Linux/OSX)... 
it deserves a better development/debugging experience than PS-ISE.. the natural evolution would be into VS-IDE (I use VSCode but for debug purposes it is not ideal... and PS-ISE fails debuging GUI applications)...

Comment: this page >>> PowerShell Tools for Visual Studio - Visual Studio Marketplace — https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2017-18561 <<< seems to say there are two levels for that plugin - free and pro.

Comment: @ZEE PS-ISE fails debugging any applications, lol

Comment: I've found the debugging for Powershell in VSCode to be pretty good, there is a good reference here: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/debugging-powershell-script-in-visual-studio-code-part-1/ is there a specific issue you are having with it?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2019 CE doesn't have default Powershell tools, it means you can't create powershell projects. You need to install "PowerShell tools for Visual Studio" from "Visual Studio Marketplace".

- Goto Visual Studio => Extension
- Search for "Powershell"
- Install "Powershell Tools for Visual Studio"
- Restart Visual studio

Next time when you open Visual studio 2019 CE, you can able to create either "Powershell Module project" or "Powershell Script project"

Comment: note that "[PowerShell tools for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AdamRDriscoll.PowerShellToolsforVisualStudio2017-18561)" is 3rd party, [paid product](https://ironmansoftware.com/powershell-pro-tools/).

Comment: @Fowl It actually used to be a free product, but sometime between 2017 and now it became paid.